# How do you trigger or "simulate" a wheel event on a jQuery handsontable with selenium/javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium, handsontable

My ultimate goal is to be able to scroll to the bottom of a handsontable and add a row of data programmatically ("manually") with a python/selenium script (javascript can be executed as well with the `driver.execute_script(js_script)` function). I cant just add a row of data without scrolling because all the elements of the table are not loaded until you scroll them into view. I have tried many ideas to no anvil using anything from jQuery functions like `$('selector').trigger(evt)` and the selenium `ActionChains` class, but none of it has worked for me. Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
var e = jQuery.Event('wheel', {deltaY: 120}); 
$('#am-editor-table > div > div.wtHider > div.wtSpreader > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)').trigger(e);
```

but this doesn't work either. (The deltaY is a property of the wheel event and making it positive causes a downward scroll.) Here is the website that I'm working with: https://live.amcharts.com/. Just create a chart and you'll see the table I'm talking about. Here is the source code of the handler that handles a mouse wheel event on the handsontable, which can be found using a event listener breakpoint in google dev mode:

```
function handler(event) {
            var orgEvent = event || window.event, args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1), delta = 0, deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0, absDelta = 0, absDeltaXY = 0, fn;
            event = $.event.fix(orgEvent);
            event.type = "mousewheel";
            if (orgEvent.wheelDelta) {
                delta = orgEvent.wheelDelta;
            }
            if (orgEvent.detail) {
                delta = orgEvent.detail * -1;
            }
            if (orgEvent.deltaY) {
                deltaY = orgEvent.deltaY * -1;
                delta = deltaY;
            }
            if (orgEvent.deltaX) {
                deltaX = orgEvent.deltaX;
                delta = deltaX * -1;
            }
            if (orgEvent.wheelDeltaY !== undefined) {
                deltaY = orgEvent.wheelDeltaY;
            }
            if (orgEvent.wheelDeltaX !== undefined) {
                deltaX = orgEvent.wheelDeltaX * -1;
            }
            absDelta = Math.abs(delta);
            if (!lowestDelta || absDelta < lowestDelta) {
                lowestDelta = absDelta;
            }
            absDeltaXY = Math.max(Math.abs(deltaY), Math.abs(deltaX));
            if (!lowestDeltaXY || absDeltaXY < lowestDeltaXY) {
                lowestDeltaXY = absDeltaXY;
            }
            fn = delta > 0 ? 'floor' : 'ceil';
            delta = Math[fn](delta / lowestDelta);
            deltaX = Math[fn](deltaX / lowestDeltaXY);
            deltaY = Math[fn](deltaY / lowestDeltaXY);
            args.unshift(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);
            return ($.event.dispatch || $.event.handle).apply(this, args);
        }
```

I'm going to be honest, I have no idea how the handsontable works internally and its documentation is quite poor. It really feels like I should be able to scroll a specific element without having to know all this but nothing has worked so I have just gone down this giant rabbit hole. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Hi. Can't you just use `scrollViewportTo()` method from Handsontable API ? (ref : https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/Core.html#scrollViewportTo)

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right track. I ended up using the `setDataAtCell()` function from the handsontable API. This is exactly what I did: `var rowCount = $("#am-editor-table").handsontable("countRows"); $("#am-editor-table").handsontable("setDataAtCell", [[rowCount - 1,0,"{0}"],[rowCount-1,1,{1}],[rowCount - 1,2,{2}]]);` (The { } are replaced by the data.)